# Laravel 8 Mutators on livewire v2

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-8

Is there anyway to create a Laravel Mutators (getters and Setters) inside a Model and call it in a Livewire component

Example

```
     /*first_name to lower*/
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
       
        $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
    }
```

and in component LW

```
public $User; //ref to Model User
    public function storeUser(Brand $brand)
    {   

       $this->User->first_name = 'Sally'; //You can't do this
        dd($this->brand);
    }
```

Is there any way to achieve this example..

Comment: as long `$this->User` it is `User` model instance you can access all the laravel model feature

Comment: didn't work for me.